Split shapefile according to DEM file boundaries
As you can see in the image, the shapefile extends outside the DEM file. How can I split the shapefile to fit the DEM file boundaries exactly?
I will use this DEM file as a water mark. So the dimensions need to be exactly the same. One will be the normal DEM file and the other will be the watermark.


Processing>Layer Tools> Extract Layer Extent (DEM) then clip your shapefile

You could use the processing algorithm "Vector overlay - Extract/clip by extent", setting the "Extent" parameter as "Calculate from layer" and selecting your DEM layer's name and checking the "Clip features to extent" checkbox.
